# Is the Triton eInk display a viable option for future ereaders?

Tags: hardware, ebook-readers, screens, color, e-ink

The new [Triton](http://eink.com/display_products_triton.html) display by eInk Technologies allows eInk screens to display color. This would be very useful for features like images and highlighting. Is it a viable option for mainstream ereader displays? Specifically,

- Does it significantly lower battery life?
- Does it affect reading quality (e.g. blurrier or more artifacts)?
- Would it require too much of a price increase?

An answer from someone who has an Ectaco Jetbook Color would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Triton display is an E Ink display so it should greatly reduced power consumption when compared to a conventional LCD display. According to the [E Ink website](http://eink.com/display_products_triton.html) the Triton display has a similar crispness as an monochrome E Ink display. The [price for the Ectaco Jetbook Color](http://www.jetbookk12.com/checkout?action=cart-add&item=22671&siteId=36) using this display is $499.95. However the price of future color E Ink displays could decrease.